# Linux bash scripting for 2 folders at the same time

Tags: linux, bash

This is the bash executible command of mine:

```
while read line
do
./ngram -order 1 -lm path1/$line -ppl path2/$line -debug 4 > path3/$line
done < input_list_of_files
```

So, I have two folders one in path1 and the other in path2. Path 1 and Path 2 have same file names but with different extensions. For example,
Path1 has many files with extension ".txt" (file1.txt) and path2 has many files with extension ".title" (file1.title).

That is, path1 has folder folder1 which has files file1.txt, file2.txt, file3.txt and so on.. Similarly, path 2 has folder folder2 which has files like, file1.title, file2.title, file3.title and so on..

The list_of_files has the data:

```
file1.txt
file2.txt
file3.txt
```

and so on...

I want to input file1.txt after the "-lm" option and input file1.title after the "-ppl" option. This works fine when I operate it for one single file at a time.

That is, when file1.txt is entered after "-lm", then at the same time, we should have file1.title after "-ppl" .

I want to do a batch computation for all the files in the folder simultaneously by inputting same file names but different extensions at the same time. How do I do it? Please help!

The example I have used:

```
./ngram -order 1 -lm Path1/Army_recruitment.txt -ppl Path2/Army_recruitment.title -debug 4 > Path3/Army_recruitment.txt
```

Output file looks like:

```
 military troop deployment number need
p( military | <s> )     = [1gram] 0.00426373 [ -2.37021 ]
p( troop | military ...)    = [1gram] 0.00476793 [ -2.32167 ]
p( deployment | troop ...)  = [1gram] 0.00045413 [ -3.34282 ]
p( number | deployment ...)     = [1gram] 0.0015224 [ -2.81747 ]
p( need | number ...)   = [1gram] 0.000778574 [ -3.1087 ]
p( </s> | need ...)     = [OOV] 0 [ -inf ]
1 sentences, 5 words, 0 OOVs
1 zeroprobs, logprob= -13.9609 ppl= 619.689 ppl1= 3091.84 
5 words, rank1= 0 rank5= 0 rank10= 0
6 words+sents, rank1wSent= 0 rank5wSent= 0 rank10wSent= 0 qloss=    0.998037 absloss= 0.998036

file Army_recruitment_title.txt: 1 sentences, 5 words, 0 OOVs
1 zeroprobs, logprob= -13.9609 ppl= 619.689 ppl1= 3091.84
5 words, rank1= 0 rank5= 0 rank10= 0
6 words+sents, rank1wSent= 0 rank5wSent= 0 rank10wSent= 0 qloss=   0.998037 absloss= 0.998036
```

This output is generated as per the executable ./ngram. This is from a package.

Comment: Could you clarify the question by providing sample contents of `input_list_of_files` and the directory listing of the `path1` and `path2` directories?

Comment: I have edited it. Please have a look.

Comment: sorry please check now... edited it clearly now

Comment: This question still has no expected output.

Comment: pluse-uno for improving your question. Good luck to all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
# As suggested by @CharlesDuffy: use read -r to ensure that text is taken literally
while read -r line ; do
    name="${line%.txt}"     # Strip off .txt extension
    ./ngram -order 1 -lm "path1/$name.txt" -ppl "path2/$name.title" -debug 4 > "path3/$name"
done < input_list_of_files
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the command `basename` to strip path suffixes in addition to the directory name. So:

```
while read line
do
path2file=$(basename $line .txt).title
./ngram -order 1 -lm path1/$line -ppl path2/$path2file -debug 4 > path3/$line
done < input_list_of_files
```

(That assumes you still want `.txt` at the end of the output file)

Comment: That's crazy inefficient compared to a parameter-expansion approach

Comment: Instead consider `path2file=${line%.txt}.title` -- no fork for a subshell, no exec'ing an external tool.

Comment: ...also, you're missing a ton of quotes here, so this code will behave very badly with filenames with spaces (run it through http://shellcheck.net/ to have those pointed out), and because it doesn't use the `-r` argument to `read`, it'll misbehave with filenames containing literal backslashes as well.